# How can I get JSON file with webview from local html

Tags: json, download, blob, android-webview, android-contentresolver

I want to get a JSON file from my HTML file in the assets folder.
But I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:`  error in my app.
The DownloadListener returns a URL of `blob:file:///bf92b937-be38-43d4-9bda-ad4e1e7b98ae`.
But I cannot get data from this URL.
This page is a local HTML file in the assets folder.
How can I read the `blob:file:///bf92b937-be38-43d4-9bda-ad4e1e7b98ae` URL?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.setMinimumHeight(500);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(
        new WebChromeClient(){
            public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
                 Log.d(TAG,cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId());
                 return true;
            }
        }
    );
    Log.d(TAG, "test start:");
    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            String METHOD = "setMyWebView:onDownloadStart" ;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDownloadStart: " + url);
            Log.d(TAG, "contentDisposition:" + contentDisposition + " mimetype:" + mimetype + " contentlength:" + contentLength);
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
            try (InputStream inputStream = resolver.openInputStream(downloadUri)) {
                // Parse the JSON data
                byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                inputStream.read(bytes);
                String jsonString = new String(bytes);
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON: " + jsonString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onDownloadStart: ", e);
            }
        }
    });
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test/test.html");
}
```

}

**asset/test/test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
        jsondata = JSON.parse('{"key":"A","data":"123"}');
        const textjson = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
        console.log(textjson);
        const jsonname = "TEST.json";
        const downLoadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downLoadLink.download = jsonname;
        downLoadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([textjson], {type: "text.plain"}));
        downLoadLink.dataset.downloadurl = ["text/plain", downLoadLink.download, downLoadLink.href].join(":");
        downLoadLink.click();
        downLoadLink.remove();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**log**

```
D  test start:
D  {"key":"A","data":"123"} -- From line 12 of file:///android_asset/test/test.html
D  onDownloadStart: blob:file:///bf92b937-be38-43d4-9bda-ad4e1e7b98ae
D  contentDisposition: mimetype:text/plain contentlength:24
E  onDownloadStart: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: blob:file:///bf92b937-be38-43d4-9bda-ad4e1e7b98ae
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1187)
    at olto.java_conf.gr.jp.testapp.MainActivity$2.onDownloadStart(MainActivity.java:71)
    at WV.B6.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-609914436:483)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```